# what is the meaning of 'Artifact" in software testing?

Tags: testing

during defect raise in software testing , i came across a word "Artifact" , what it actually means? can anybody explain? I'm really frustrated by searching the actual meaning of it in google.

Answer (score 17):

It usually means something like "a file created during testing". For example, the log file is an artifact. If your tests create temporary files, they are artifacts. If your test dowloads images, those are artifacts.

Artifacts can mean other things besides files (which is why we say "artifact" rather than "file"). For example, an artifact could be a row added to a database.

Depending on the context, it could also mean files you need in order to perform the test (eg: "for this test you need the following artifacts...")

In short, an artifact is something created or used by the test suite.

Answer (score 1):

The artifacts produced, let's say, for a given release are all the different "units of products" that are available. It's better to have an example to understand. Imagine you have to test a single product but that this products comes 2 you in 2 versions (.msi file for Win and .dmg for Mac) plus 3 upgrade scripts for the different databases you could as a backend, then you have 5 artifacts in your hands that you should test.

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts are also the documents used to execute different things. For example SRS, FS, Test plan, Test cycle plan, Test cases of different types.

They are used for different purposes. Other than the above mentioned artifacts there are design documents, ERD, DFD, etc.

These documents are needed to execute different tasks during different stages of SDLC.